# Asynchronous blocking callback from server to client

Tags: c#, wcf

In WCF, I have a client and a server, I want the server to make a asynchronous blocking callback to the client using `BeginInvoke(),` how this can be implemented on the server side?

Comment: Async and blocking are contrary. And you won't need BeginInvoke. The question needs a lot more detail.

Comment: "*asynchronous blocking*" - a good example of an [oxymoron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron) :)